# Hiding a Progress Spinner after download is complete

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, spinner, httpresponse

I have a JSP, with an HTML form, where a user gives a couple of inputs.  After submitting the JSP calls some server-side Java code to create a report.  Based on the inputs this report could take a few seconds or a few minutes.  After the Java code completes it sends ouput in the form of an Excel file back to the browser in the Response object.  This gives the user the standard prompt to Open or Save the file.

During report creation I have a little animation that displays fine after submission, but after the user Opens or Saves the file, the animation remains on the screen.  I want the animation to be hidden after the user Opens or Saves.

My thought was using the javascript timeout and interval functions but because of the variability of the report creation I have no idea what to set the duration for.  I've tried to find ways to key off of download completion or when the user clicks on Open or Save but that doesn't seem to be possible.  I'm looking for any other ideas because right now I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Set the average duration of report creating time beacuse i don't think there is a way to assign different durations for different reports

Comment: Another alternative would be to close the window after the user is prompted with the Open/Save dialog box.